# Copy Non-continuous Cell Values

Tags: performance, vba, excel

Backstory: I'm creating department level workbooks that contains director-level information, so I can't use a single workbook (as easy as it would make this). I need to split (and combine) 4 workbooks into 140 or more. I manage to do this relatively quickly (~30 minutes), but I was hoping to speed it up more.

For each sheet I create, I need certain filtered columns from the original 4 reports. After filtering the reports, I have this macro copy the columns:

```vb
Sub copyVisibleCells(fromWb As String, fromWS As String, fromCol As Integer, towb As String, toWS As String, toCol As Integer)

On Error GoTo errhnd

    Dim myCopyRange As Range
    Dim toCopyRange As Range
    ' Get the intersection of the column we want, and the range that has been used
    Set myCopyRange = Intersect(Workbooks(fromWb).Sheets(fromWS).Columns(fromCol), Workbooks(fromWb).Sheets(fromWS).UsedRange)
    ' If there's at least one visible cell (there was some error here once about trying to copy 0 cells, go figure)
    If myCopyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
        ' Remove the first row (swap the 1 with a 2) to remove the headers
        Set myCopyRange = Workbooks(fromWb).Sheets(fromWS).Range(Left(myCopyRange.Address, InStr(myCopyRange.Address, ":") - 2) & "2:" & Right(myCopyRange.Address, Len(myCopyRange.Address) - InStr(myCopyRange.Address, ":")))
        ' Copy the cells over: works, but seems slow
        myCopyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Workbooks(towb).Sheets(toWS).Cells(6, toCol).PasteSpecial(xlValues)
    End If
    ' Done
    Exit Sub
errhnd:
    Debug.Print (vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error: " & err.Number & vbNewLine & err.Description & vbNewLine & "Press F8 to see error location")
    Stop
    Resume
End Sub
```

Is there a better way to do this? I was under the impression that Range.Copy and Range.PasteSpecial(xlValues) were very inefficient much like I've heard of Range.Select

Comment: @Downvoter: An explanation? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is Code Review, not Stack Overflow - see our [help/on-topic] for more details, but long story short if your code isn't working as intended, it's not ready for a peer review, and that makes the post off-topic on this site.

Comment: I mean, it does work with the first method (Copy + PasteSpecial), I just thought it was running slowly. I was trying to show that I was attempting the problem and not immediately turning to the internet to fix my code for me :) Edit- Thank you though

Comment: If it's about performance bottlenecks and general enhancements, feel free to [edit] your post to remove any ambiguity about whether the code you're submitting for review works as intended or not; the code under review should be the working code you're currently using. You'll find CR is a lot more laid back than SO; SO wants straight-to-the-point and what-did-you-try, CR wants all the context and then some, and only needs to see the working code that needs to be reviewed.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! I edited the post, but if anyone needs/wants more context, let me know, I can post more about this.

Comment: There are two main parts to your code: the copy/paste operation and creating/opening/closing workbooks (i.e. file I/O -- which is not shown in your code above). While you might get some performance improvement in the copy/paste section, there is likely NO performance improvement possible for the file I/O, especially if you are reading/writing to a network drive. That's a bottleneck in your enterprise, not VBA.

Comment: @PeterT Thank you, I hadn't thought of that! I'm generating each report and copying to the network during the code. I bet it would be a lot faster to copy them over when I'm done and I've verified that they all look correct. Plus I'm uploading to SharePoint later anyways

Comment: @PeterT Wow. You were so right. I started generating all the files in my %Temp% directory and copying them at the end. The reports generate about 10 times faster. :O Thank you so much!